# Sulu CMS GET-request error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, sulu

I have an AJAX GET-request which should return to me the list of categories but I have got an SQL error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`

My request URl is next: `http://my-domain.com/admin/api/categories?flat=true&sortBy=depth&sortOrder=asc&fields=name,id`

What is the best way to solve this problem? Should I change mysql `.cnf` file or it's can be fixed in the code?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: yes, but sql-query is generated in vendor, so I can't change vendors code. That's why I'm asking what the best solution of this problem in Sulu

Comment: MySQL has a compatibility mode to allow those invalid GROUP BY's. Perhaps you can set it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem was in MySQL compatibility.

So, I just change `mysql.cnf` file by adding following lines:
`[mysqld] sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`